# zipimport.ZipImportError: can't decompress data; zlib not available

Tags: rhel, python, pip, python3

On RHEL 6.6, I installed Python 3.5.1 from source. I am trying to install pip3 via get-pip.py, but I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get-pip.py", line 19177, in <module>
    main()
  File "get-pip.py", line 194, in main
    bootstrap(tmpdir=tmpdir)
  File "get-pip.py", line 82, in bootstrap
    import pip
zipimport.ZipImportError: can't decompress data; zlib not available
```

It works for the Python 2.6.6 installed. I have looked online for answers, but I cannot seem to find any that works for me.

edit: `yum search zlib`

```
jzlib.i686 : JZlib re-implementation of zlib in pure Java
perl-Compress-Raw-Zlib.i686 : Low-Level Interface to the zlib compression library
perl-Compress-Zlib.i686 : A module providing Perl interfaces to the zlib compression library
perl-IO-Zlib.i686 : Perl IO:: style interface to Compress::Zlib
zlib.i686 : The zlib compression and decompression library
zlib-debuginfo.i686 : Debug information for package zlib
zlib-devel.i686 : Header files and libraries for Zlib development
perl-IO-Compress-Zlib.i686 : Perl interface to allow reading and writing of gzip and zip data

  Name and summary matches only, use "search all" for everything.
```

Comment: can you show the exact command.

Comment: can you search for `zlib` package.

Comment: I run `python3 get-pip.py` to show the error message above, but it works for `python get-pip.py`. Yes, I can run `yum search zlib`.

Comment: Based on your comments, you do have zlib installed, but perhaps there's a python-zlib wrapper you need?

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: on macos, we can `brew install zlib` 

Comment: I fixed this by copying `zlib.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` to `/usr/local/lib/python*/lib-dynaload`.

Comment: In RHEL 7, sudo yum install zlib-devel.x86_64 works for me

Answer (score 166):

**Ubuntu 16.10+** and Python 3.7 dev

```
sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev
```

Note: I only put this here because it was the top search result for the error, but this resolved my issue.

Update: also the case for ubuntu 14.04LTS and base kernel at 4.1+

Comment: Thanks! it helped me resolve the issue installing 3.7.1 on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Helped resolve issue for python3+ on Ubuntu 20

Answer (score 55):

---

The solution is : # `yum install zlib-devel`

---

---

Comment: I tried that. It says `Setting up Install Process
rhel6_latest                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         | 1.9 kB     00:00     
Package zlib-devel-1.2.3-29.el6.i686 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do`, but I still get the zipimport error.

Comment: did not solve my problem

Comment: This should be the current answer. Thanks

Answer (score 9):

Simply copy paste this [code](https://medium.com/@pimterry/setting-up-pyenv-on-os-x-with-homebrew-56c7541fd331):

```
CFLAGS="-I$(brew --prefix readline)/include -I$(brew --prefix openssl)/include -I$(xcrun --show-sdk-path)/usr/include" \
LDFLAGS="-L$(brew --prefix readline)/lib -L$(brew --prefix openssl)/lib" \
PYTHON_CONFIGURE_OPTS=--enable-unicode=ucs2 \
pyenv install -v 3.6.0
```

Comment: This doesn't seem like RHEL.

Comment: It's macOS only solution (and brew also should be installed as pre-requisite). Still - good partial solution

Answer (score 3):

you don't have decompress tool,You should install `zlib` .

**Updated Answer**

first check if its installed

`yum list python-gzipstream`

If not then run the below to install

`yum install python-gzipstream.noarch`

I have this installed on my system

```
 yum list python-gzipstream
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.webwerks.com
 * epel: ftp.kddilabs.jp
 * extras: centos.webwerks.com
 * updates: mirror.nbrc.ac.in
Available Packages
python-gzipstream.noarch                                                                1.4.3-1.el6                                                                 epel
```

Comment: I ran `yum install zlib`. I get that I already have the latest version. I still get the same error.

Comment: check the updated answer

Comment: For `yum list python-gzipstream`, I get `Error: No matching Packages to list
`, and for `yum install python-gzipstream.noarch`, I get `No package python-gzipstream.noarch available.
Error: Nothing to do`

Comment: can you show is us the output of `yum repolist` & `yum search zlib`.

Comment: For repolist, `repo id                                                  repo name                                                                                    status
rhel6_latest                                             Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6Server - i386 - latest                                             11,637
repolist: 11,637`

Comment: I put the search results in the edited question.

Answer (score 3):

Throwing my 2cents. I've been dealing with this issue for the past 3 hours and realized that python3.6 for me was installed was in /usr/local/bin/.

I remade the configure with --prefix==/usr/bin and pip installed.

> Installing collected packages: setuptools, pip
>   Successfully installed pip-9.0.1 setuptools-28.8.0

Answer (score 1):

The `zlib` module is an optional feature for python and it seems that the version of python3.5 in RHEL 6.6 does not include it. You can verify this:

```
python3 -c "import zlib"
```

So you'll either need to obtain a zlib enabled version of python (or python libraries) or rebuild python from source with the zlib feature enabled - see here for help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12344970/building-python-from-source-with-zlib-support